# Release APK not working for API 6.0 and below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I just build a release APK and tried it. It works fine in all the devices that is having API of 7.0 or high. But when I tried testing it in marshmallow or devices with lower API than marshmallow, then the apk was not installed. It showed the error message App not installed. I have my minSdkVersion as 21 but still this problem happens.

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leadershipboard"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
     implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.4.2'
     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Also While generating the signed APK I ticked both V1 and V2 checkboxes. Since I saw that in a solution but that didn't work.

What is the problem here and how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this app already installed on this device? Maybe you were using that same device as an emulator.
In this case, uninstall the earlier app and try again.

Also, if you have installed any app with same package name (i.e. maybe you changed the app name or tried opening some specific activity on your device), look out for all those in your applications and uninstall all of them.

Hope this works!

Comment: I have tried it many devices of different api in which I have not installed this app before and out of that all devices, the device with marshmallow or below shows me the error app not installed.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get the apk? 
I hope you got it like this:
go to  Build ---> Build APK(s) ---> locate apk and share

Comment: Try a couple more things:
1. Clean your project and build again.

2. Disable Google Play Protect on your device

To disable Google Play Protect. Open "Play Store" application => tap on Menu button => select "Play Protect" option => Disable the options "Scan device for security threats".

Comment: Also, in your manifest, set this under application:

testOnly="false" and android:debuggable="true"